# iTextPDF : PDF/X conformance

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I am using iText to generate PDF. I want to generate PDF with PDF/X-1A or PDF/X-3 standard. 
iText has a method in PDFWriter to set this standard using setPDFXConformance.
I have used this method, and PDF opened using adobe is showing the standard as PDF/X.

Question: Do I have to do something more(other than just setPDFXConformance) to make the generated PDF compliant to PDF/X standard? There are some requirements of PDF/X like fonts should be enabled, images should be CMYK etc.
Does setPDFXConformance handle all this?

Comment: No, setting PDF/X conformance doesn't automatically trigger the use of CMYK, the embedding of fonts, etc... Instead, it throws an error when you do something that violates PDF/X conformance. Note that this might not be full proof: iText throws an error for the usual violations, but might not throw an error for *all* violations. Since there were very little interest for PDF/X, we at iText focused on PDF/A and PDF/UA, and as far as I know, we don't even have PDF/X conformance checking anymore in recent versions of iText.

Comment: When does it throw error? because I tried setting to PDF/X-1a when my images are RGB. PDF got generated without errors. We have to use PDF/X because our PDF is being intended to be sent to an external vendor for printing.  Therefore, conforming to PDF/X is important for us.

Comment: As I said: it does not throw an exception for *all* violations. Some PDF/X requirements are *your* responsibility.

Comment: You can always use the Pdf Accessibility Checker (PAC) to check the conformance. Adobe reader also has a tool called "preflight" which is capable of checking the conformance.